# AlertDialog Custom Layout - Erro de NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

Fala galera beleza? Então, eu tentei criar um Aler Dialog Customizado, mas toda vez que eu tento salvar, ele da um erro de NullPointerException, porém não sei qual é a causa. O código do metodo que tem o Alert é este:

```
Button btnAlertDataConsulta;
Button btnAlertHoraConsulta;
EditText edtNomeDrConsulta;

@OnClick(R.id.consultas_btn_agendarconsulta)
void agendarConsulta(){

        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        consultas = new ArrayList<>();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext());
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_consultas, null));
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        builder.setTitle("Nova Consulta");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Salvar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                btnAlertDataConsulta = alert.findViewById(R.id.btn_alert_data_consulta);
                btnAlertHoraConsulta = alert.findViewById(R.id.btn_alert_hora_consulta);
                edtNomeDrConsulta = alert.findViewById(R.id.edt_alert_nome_dr_consulta);

                btnAlertDataConsulta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.d("LOG", "ALERT DATA CONSULTA ");
                    }
                });

                btnAlertHoraConsulta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.d("LOG", "ALERT HORA CONSULTA ");
                    }
                });

                consultas.add(new Consulta("Dra. Jane Doe", "28/08", "15h"));
                bDAO.inserirConsultas(new Consulta("Dra. Jane Doe", "28/08", "15h"));
                loadRecycler(consultas);
                Helper.snackbarFast(getView(), "Consulta adicionada!");

                Log.i("LOG", "Data: 21/01 | Nome Dr: "+edtNomeDrConsulta.getText().toString()+" | Hora: 21h");
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

e ele me retorna este erro:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                                       at
>   projeto.teste.com.br.projeto_app.view.ConsultasFragment$2.onClick(ConsultasFragment.java:134)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:162)
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

Answer (score 1):

```
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    consultas = new ArrayList<>();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext());

    //modificação
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_consultas, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    //fim modificação

    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    builder.setTitle("Nova Consulta");

    builder.setPositiveButton("Salvar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            //modificação
            btnAlertDataConsulta = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_alert_data_consulta);
            btnAlertHoraConsulta = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_alert_hora_consulta);
            edtNomeDrConsulta = view.findViewById(R.id.edt_alert_nome_dr_consulta);
            //fim modificação

            btnAlertDataConsulta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("LOG", "ALERT DATA CONSULTA ");
                }
            });

            btnAlertHoraConsulta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("LOG", "ALERT HORA CONSULTA ");
                }
            });

            consultas.add(new Consulta("Dra. Jane Doe", "28/08", "15h"));
            bDAO.inserirConsultas(new Consulta("Dra. Jane Doe", "28/08", "15h"));
            loadRecycler(consultas);
            Helper.snackbarFast(getView(), "Consulta adicionada!");

            Log.i("LOG", "Data: 21/01 | Nome Dr: "+edtNomeDrConsulta.getText().toString()+" | Hora: 21h");
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Como você quer usar botões do layout que inflou, você tem que buscar da view, no caso estava buscando do Alert, por isso o NullPointer. Apenas um detalhe, o onclick dos botões btnAlertDataConsulta e btnAlertHoraConsulta não vão executar. Você precisa declarar tudo isso fora do onclick do positive button, o findview e os onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que tenho uma versão resumida que pode te ajudar:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
.setTitle("Salvar ?").
setMessage("Deseja Salvar ?")
.setPositiveButton("Salvar",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton){
        consultas.add(new Consulta("Dra. Jane Doe", "28/08", "15h"));
    }
})
.setNegativeButton("Cancelar",null).show();
```

Comment: mas esta não tem um layout customizado :(